# MVC - return a view based on a route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC how can I return a view depending on the route that is used to access the controller/action.

I want to reuse a controller/action for another part of my site but I want to return a slightly different view

So for example these 2 URLs should hit the same controller but return different views:

/admin/reports/tickets
/client/admin/report/sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the "meat" of the controller action into another class that both controller actions call.

For example:

```
// /admin/reports/tickets
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Tickets(int customerId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var purchaseTransactions = db.Transactions
                .Where(trx => 
                    trx.Type == 'P'  // Purchase
                    && trx.CustomerId == customerId)
            return View(purchaseTransactions);
        }
    }
}

// /client/admin/report/sales
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Sales(int customerId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var purchaseTransactions = db.Transactions
                .Where(trx => 
                    trx.Type == 'P'  // Purchase
                    && trx.CustomerId == customerId)
            return View(purchaseTransactions);
        }
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
public class TicketService
{
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> GetTicketPurchasesForCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDataContext())
        {
            var purchaseTransactions = db.Transactions
                .Where(trx => 
                    trx.Type == 'P'  // Purchase
                    && trx.CustomerId == customerId)
            return purchaseTransactions;
        }
    }
}

// /admin/reports/tickets
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Tickets(int customerId)
    {
        TicketService svc = new TicketService();
        IEnumerable<Transaction> tickets = svc.GetTicketPurchasesForCustomer(customerId);
        return View(tickets);
    }
}

// /client/admin/report/sales
public class ReportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Sales(int customerId)
    {
        TicketService svc = new TicketService();
        IEnumerable<Transaction> sales = svc.GetTicketPurchasesForCustomer(customerId);
        return View(sales);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's probably the best idea in that it wont create confusion when I come back to the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure routes for this scenario, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "tickets",
    url: "admin/reports/tickets",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Tickets" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "sales",
    url: "client/admin/report/sales",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Sales" }
);
```

So each route navigates to the same controller, but a different action method, which allows you to render a different view.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Tickets() {}
    public ActionResult Sales() {}
}
```

I suggest keeping the action methods separate, don't try to be clever and use the same action method and then use some logic to determine what to show. It just makes things messy.